# Initialize Structure Member Arrays in D

Tags: arrays, struct, initialization, d

How to automatically initialize a member array of a structure in D?

```
struct MyStruct {
    ubyte[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // Will Fail
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try square brackets:

```
struct MyStruct {
    ubyte[] a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // Compiles
}
```

[Here](http://dlang.org/expression.html#ArrayLiteral) is the syntax for array literals.